# Como ordenar um struct dentro de um struct

Tags: c++, struct, classificação

Estou querendo fazer ordenação de um struct que está referenciado dentro de outra struct:

*Detalhe: pode ser uma ordenação usando selection sort*

```
typedef struct{
    int tipo;
    char dispositivo[50];
    int prioridade;
}Perif;

typedef struct no{
    Perif info;
    struct no* prox;
}Aux_Perif;

Aux_Perif* criarLista(){
    return NULL;
}

void imprimirLista(Aux_Perif** lista, int size){
    Aux_Perif* aux = *lista;
    while (aux != NULL){
    std::cout << "DISPOSITIVO: ";
    std::cout << aux->info.dispositivo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PRIORIDADE: ";
    std::cout << aux->info.prioridade << std::endl;
    aux = aux->prox;
    }
}

void inserirFinal(Aux_Perif** perifericos, Perif barramento){
    Aux_Perif* novo = (Aux_Perif*)new Aux_Perif;
    novo->info = barramento;
    Aux_Perif* aux = *perifericos;
    Aux_Perif* anterior = NULL;
    if (*perifericos == NULL){
        *perifericos = novo;
    }else{
        while(aux != NULL){
            anterior = aux;
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
    anterior->prox = novo;
    }

}

int main(){
int solic;
int cont = 0;
int aux = 0, prior = 0;
Aux_Perif* perifericos;
perifericos = criarLista();
std::cout << "Entre com o número de solicitações: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> solic;
std::cout << "Periféricos:\n1. Impressora\n2. Mouse\n3. Teclado\n4. Scanner\n5. Roteador\n6. Disco Rígido" << std::endl;
std::cout << "De acordo com os números e Periféricos acima, insira a ordem de entrada das solicitações e sua prioridade" << std::endl;
while (cont < solic){
    Perif ordem;
    std::cin >> aux >> prior;
    switch (aux){
        case 1:
            //ordem.dispositivo = 'Impressora';
            strcpy(ordem.dispositivo, "Impressora");
            break;
        case 2: 
            strcpy(ordem.dispositivo , "Mouse") ;
            break;
        case 3: 
            strcpy(ordem.dispositivo , "Teclado");
            break;
        case 4:
            strcpy(ordem.dispositivo , "Scanner");
            break;
        case 5:
            strcpy(ordem.dispositivo , "Roteador");
            break;
        case 6: 
            strcpy(ordem.dispositivo , "Disco Rígido");
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
            break;
    }

    ordem.tipo = aux;
    ordem.prioridade = prior;
    cont++;
    inserirFinal(&perifericos, ordem);
    //delete[] ordem;

}
std::cout << "Daisy Chaining utilizando método de ordem a chegada ou entrada." << std::endl;
imprimirLista(&perifericos, solic);
std::cout << "Método por Prioridade: " << std::endl;
imprimirLista(&perifericos, solic);
return 0;
}
```

Nesse caso, eu quero fazer a ordenação de acordo com o `Aux_perif -> info -> prioridade`. Ajuda aê, pessoal!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
void selectionsort_AuxPerif(Aux_Perif **vetor, int tamanho) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {
        int menor = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < tamanho; j++) {
            if (vetor[menor]->info->prioridade > vetor[j]->info->prioridade) menor = j;
        }
        if (menor != i) {
            Aux_Perif *temp = vetor[menor];
            vetor[menor] = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void ordena_AuxPerif(Aux_Perif **perif) {
    // 1. Se a lista está vazia, então nem faz nada.
    if (perif == NULL) return;

    // 2. Descobre o tamanho da lista.
    int tamanho = 0;
    Aux_Perif *v;
    for (v = *perif; v != NULL; v = v->prox) {
        tamanho++;
    }

    // 3. Monta um vetor com os elementos da lista.
    Aux_Perif **vetor = (Aux_Perif **) malloc(sizeof(Aux_Perif *) * tamanho);
    int i = 0
    for (v = *perif; v != NULL; v = v->prox, i++) {
        vetor[i] = v;
    }

    // 4. Ordena o vetor.
    selectionsort_AuxPerif(vetor, tamanho);

    // 5. Corrige os ponteiros de acordo com a nova ordenação.
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {
        vetor[i]->prox = vetor[i + 1];
    }
    vetor[i]->prox = NULL;

    // 6. Corrige o ponteiro para o início da lista.
    *perif = vetor[0];

    // 7. Deleta o vetor auxiliar.
    free(vetor);
}
```

Ah, um outro detalhe que vi no seu código é que a função `imprimirLista` nunca utiliza o parâmetro `size`. Você pode retirar este parâmetro se preferir.

Além disso, caso você deseje substituir o método de ordenação por algum outro, é só trocar a chamada à função `selectionsort_AuxPerif` por alguma outra que tenha os parâmetros do mesmo tipo. Por exemplo:

```
void mergesort_AuxPerif(Aux_Perif **vetor, int tamanho) {
    if (tamanho <= 1) return;
    int meio = tamanho / 2;
    mergesort_AuxPerif(vetor, meio);
    mergesort_AuxPerif(&(vetor[meio]), tamanho - meio);

    Aux_Perif **temp = (Aux_Perif **) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(Aux_Perif *));
    int i, a = 0, b = meio;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        if (b == tamanho || (a < meio && vetor[a]->info->prioridade < vetor[b]->info->prioridade)) {
            temp[i] = vetor[a];
            a++;
        } else {
            temp[i] = vetor[b];
            b++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        vetor[i] = temp[i];
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Não me importo com o downvote, mas fico curioso com ele. Qual é a razão para votar contra? Se alguém vir dizer que é porque dei a resposta de graça, basta ver que isso aqui é apenas um pequeno detalhe de implementação dentro do contexto do que o OP está fazendo (converter a lista em array, usar o selectionsort que você acha facilmente na internet e arrumar de volta os ponteiros, o que não é nada demais). Se for por alguma outra razão, eu realmente gostaria de saber.